# Как использовать значения свойства наследников в базовом классе

Tags: c#, ооп

Возможно ли в базовом классе использовать значение свойства класса наследника? Например есть базовый класс модели - Model, в котором будут методы для работы со всеми моделями, и есть 2 класса наследующиеся от модели - User и Vehicle. Возможно ли как то обращаясь через наследника к методам базового класса (например User.GetTable()) в методе базового класса получить значение свойства наследника? Код для примера:

```
namespace Test
{

class Model<T>
{
    public static string Table { get { return "base"; } }

    public Model()
    {
    }

    public static string GetTable() 
    {
        return Model<T>.Table;
    }
}

class User : Model<User>
{
    public static string Table { get { return "users"; } }

    public User()
    {
    }
}

class Vehicle : Model<Vehicle>
{
    public static string Table { get { return "vehicles"; } }

    public Vehicle()
    {
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(User.Table.ToString()); //печатает users
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.Table.ToString()); //печатает vehicles

        Console.WriteLine(User.GetTable()); //печатает base
        Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.GetTable()); //печатает base
    }
}
}
```

Я думаю, что такое возможно с помощью generic'ов, просто я делаю что-то неправильно. Если не прав - поправьте. :)

### UPD:

Совсем забыл уточнить в вопросе, возможно ли это реализовать именно используя статичные методы и свойства?

Я пишу класс для удобной работы с базой данных (по типу ORM, но гораздо проще) и я хотел использовать методы класса Model статично для получения данных, например: Model.all(), Model.find(int id) и т.д., а внутри этих методов необходимо знать из какой таблицы брать данные.

Без статичных методов и свойств все работало, но тогда приходится создавать экземпляр модели.

+ насколько правильно держать методы которые не относятся к конкретному объекту не в статике?

Comment: ООП не дружит со статикой.  [подробнее](https://habrahabr.ru/post/206082/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых, генерики тут не нужны. Во второых, наследование и прочие OOP-вещи реально работают только при работе с объектами, а не со статическими свойствами.

Вы никак не можете достать данные в коде базового класса из статических свойств класса-наследника. Просто потому, что базовый класс о классах-наследниках ничего не знает.

Ваша задача легко решается через отказ от статики и использование виртуальных свойств. Метод GetTable - нестатический, он выполняется в конкретном объекте. При вызове свойства Table рантайм смотрит на конкретный тип текущего объекта, находит соответствующую реализацию (`User.Table`/`Vehicle.Table`) и вызывает ее.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{

    class Model
    {
        public virtual string Table { get { return "base"; } }

        public Model()
        {
        }

        public string GetTable()
        {
            return this.Table;
        }
    }

    class User : Model
    {
        public override string Table { get { return "users"; } }

        public User()
        {
        }
    }

    class Vehicle : Model
    {
        public override string Table { get { return "vehicles"; } }

        public Vehicle()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new User().Table); //печатает users
            Console.WriteLine(new Vehicle().Table); //печатает vehicles

            Console.WriteLine(new User().GetTable()); //печатает users
            Console.WriteLine(new Vehicle().GetTable()); //печатает vehicles
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В случаей использования статических членов так сделать нельзя, поскольку они принадлежат типам, а не экземплярам, и понятие наследования для них "не работает". Если вы замените их на экземплярные члены и используете абстрактное/виртуальное свойство, то все получится:

```
class Model<T>
{
    public virtual string Table => "base";

    public Model()
    {
    }

    public string GetTable() 
    {
        return Table;
    }
}

class User : Model<User>
{
    public override string Table => "users";
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var user = new User();

        Console.WriteLine(user.GetTable()); //печатает users
    }
}
```

Comment: И generic можно выбросить.

Comment: @Vlad ну может автору дженерики для другого нужны, я ж не знаю.

Comment: @andreycha да, изначально я так и делал. Но при таком подходе нужно создавать экземпляр объекта для вызова методов. Я забыл уточнить что вопрос конкретно на счет статики, возможно ли так это сделать. Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать через абстрактный класс `Model`:

```
namespace Test
{

    abstract class Model
    {
        public Model()
        {
        }

        public string GetTable()
        {
            return GetTableInternal();
        }

        protected abstract string GetTableInternal();
    }

    class User : Model
    {
        public User()
        {
        }

        protected override string GetTableInternal()
        {
            return "users";
        }
    }

    class Vehicle : Model
    {
        public Vehicle()
        {
        }

        protected override string GetTableInternal()
        {
            return "vehicles";
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var user = new User();
            var vehicle = new Vehicle();

            Console.WriteLine(user.GetTable()); //печатает base
            Console.WriteLine(vehicle.GetTable()); //печатает base
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Только у автора статические методы и в этом вся проблема. Были бы нестатические всё и так бы работало

Comment: Печатает vehicles и users, а не base и base.